# Differences between Change Capture stage and Difference stage in DataStage

Tags: datastage

I'm trying to implement SCD Type1 loading using Change Capture and Difference stages in DataStage. Both these jobs are working fine without any errors, but i would like to know what was differences between these two stages and which one will deliver a better performance?

I had tried several test cases to find the differences few that i had found were

- In Change capture stage we need to have both the inputs with same number of columns and same column names with similar datatypes but that was not the case in Difference stage.

Could  someone help me to figure out what the actual important analogy between these 2 stages. (Any related web links are welcome)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not the point - they should be compareable - more important is the functionality point of view.

- The DIFFERENCE stage returns the "before" columns and after columns only in some situations (if they are not part of the key or value columns and are named differently)
- The CHANGE CAPTURE stage returns the "after" columns. BEfore columns are only available for Deletes

Comment: Thanks MichaelTiefenbacher for answering, but is it all about what the output columns that we are getting from the stage or any other differences?

Comment: Well there are more differences - like options to configure the stage or the returned codes are slightly different (per default). With Change Capture you have the "All Keys, Explicit Values" etc. options to configure its behaviour. Personally I user the Change Capture more frequently in scenarions where I need to determine deltas.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Slowly Changing Dimension stage.  It does a lot more of the work for you.